# Use custom layout only for Devise registration create and not edit in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I ma using Rails 5 and Devise.

I have a default application layout 'admin_lte' which is used in all my forms. Now I want to use a custom layout for the sign up view. In my RegistrationsController I did the following:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  layout "blank_form", only: [:create]

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    super
  end
```

But for some reason this applies the blank_form layout also for the edit action and not only the create action. I wonder why this happens...any ideas?

Comment: layout "blank_form", only: [:create], I guess layout just applies to create action as you mentioned I guess?!!!!

Comment: Yes, that's what it should do. But for some reason it uses blank_form also for my edit action.

Comment: I feel the answer is in this part " But for some reason it uses blank_form also for my edit action." Could you please make it more clear or rephrase it please?

Answer (score 0):

does `layout "blank_form", :only => [:create]` work for you?

you could also try just setting the layout to false `layout false, only: [:create]` and in the `/path/to/signup`view just paste your alternative CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

> If a layout is specified, all rendered actions will have their result rendered when the layout yields. This layout can itself depend on instance variables assigned during action performance and have access to them as any normal template would.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout

If you want to render layout only for one method you should invoke render method with layout option:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#options-for-render

In your case I recommend find what `create` method render and render the same with your custom layout